# Как обработать нажатие на RecycleView

Tags: java, android, json, recyclerview

У меня есть json-строка, из нее я достаю определнный параметр(название) и все эти названия вывожоу через RecycleView в CardView. Все отлично) Теперь мне нужно при нажатии на карточку, получить дополнительную информацию. Причем для каждой карточки своя доп.информация)
Как это сделать?

Хотелось бы также посоветоваться с вами, дополнительную информацию при нажатии выводить в новой активити или в новом фрагменте? Как будет лучше и правильнее?

Comment: В адаптере можно повесить слушатель и его описать.
Но как его описать?

Comment: `setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){@Override onClick(View v){//тут клик}});`

Comment: это понятно, меня интересует как отобразить для каждой карточки сво инфу.

Comment: дополнительную информацию из того же json или откуда?

Comment: @Y.Pashkov Да-да.

Т.е смотри. Я нажимаю на карточку и открывается дополнительная информация взятая из Json.

Суть в том,что на каждой карточке я вывел название из json, какждому названию своя дополнительная информация.

Comment: @MartinezToni Если я правильно понял, в вашем json это массив объектов (карточек). Как я понял в адаптер вы передаете только массив строк (названий). Почему бы вам не передать в адаптер массив объектов. Тогда при нажатии на item, у вас будет вся информация, ну и передадите этот весь объект далее в новую активити или фрагмент

Comment: @Y.Pashkov в моем json массив, карточек столько - сколько элементов в массиве.

В адаптер я передаю вот что holder.name.setText(mData.get(position).getName());


А вы как еще раз предлагаете?

Comment: @Y.Pashkov мне нужно сделать так:
1.Нажимаю на карточку
2. открывается новая активность или фрагмент
3.выводится инфа

Я вывожу в карточку только имя т.к мне нужно чтобы было только имя

Answer (score 2):

У адаптера будет listener в качестве проперти

```
OnItemClickListener listener
```

Где его можно определить как

```
public interface OnItemClickListener {
    void onCardPressed(CardModel cardModel);
}
```

Вы можете его засетить либо через конструктор, либо через setListener.
Далее в адаптере будет что-то похожее на такое

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            CardModel cardModel = mData.get(position);// это ваша модель у которой вы имя получали для holder.name.setText

            if (listener != null) {
                listener.onPressed(cardModel);
            }

            //open new Activity/Fragment в классе, котором определен этот листенер, т.е.
            //активити или фрагмент, где создается этот адаптер
        }
    });

}
```

Для случая если будет метод setListener у адаптера, то в активити/фрагмент где создавался адаптер

```
adapter.setListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCardClick(CardModel cardModel) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("CardModel", cardModel);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Comment: что такое cardModel, не понял немного.

Comment: Ну ваш json содержит же массив каких-то объектов, CardModel это тот самый объект из json'a. Просто я его так назвал)

Comment: Так, а  что это такое public interface OnItemClickListener {
    void onCardPressed(CardModel cardModel);
}

Comment: Это просто интерфейс, который вы будете должны создать в проекте, когда создаете класс, там можно выбрать интерфейс

Comment: У меня слишком много вопросов, тебя можно в найти в соц. сети?
Был бы рад, если бы ты ответил на мои вопросы?

Comment: https://vk.com/id65128662

Answer (score 0):

У меня похожая задача решена следующим образом:

Имеется static класс (объект articles) с List для хранения объектов и полей с доступом для всего приложения, в твоем случае, возможно, объектов взятых с json, далее, самым тонким моментом, является привязка id объекта к RecyclerView. Решил это через установку тега к объекту (как пример) TextView в этом RecyclerView

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ArticleViewHolder articleViewHolder, int position) {

    articleViewHolder.headerArticle.setText(articles.get(position).getHeader());
    articleViewHolder.descriptionArticle.setText(articles.get(position).getDescription());
    articleViewHolder.imageArticle.setImageResource(articles.get(position).getPhotoId());

    //Установка идентификатора статьи
    articleViewHolder.headerArticle.setTag(articles.get(position).getArticleId());



}
```

далее, стандартно вызывается Intent, с передачей через параметр извлеченного Id из тега:

```
    public static class ArticleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    ImageView imageArticle;
    TextView headerArticle;
    TextView descriptionArticle;

    public ArticleViewHolder(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        headerArticle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.article_preview_header_TextView);
        descriptionArticle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.article_preview_description_TextView);
        imageArticle = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.article_preview_picture_ImageView);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Context context = v.getContext();

                Intent intent = new Intent(context,ArticleActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("idArticle",headerArticle.getTag().toString());

                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

в новом Activity из Intent извлекается Id, по которому можно выбрать инетерсующий объект из массива/базы данных

Comment: сделал,как ты и сказал, карточки не реагируют на нажатие

Comment: Заметил особенность. Мгновенно реагирует при нажатии на картинку, что для меня достаточно, так как картинка занимает большую часть карточки. Видимо в других компонентах событие перехватывается.

Comment: смотри, достал я id-шник в новой активности, но как мне теперь выбрать объект из массива?

Comment: получил ID, в новой активности, но не знаю как выбрать объект из массива

Comment: Из List путем перебора for:
    protected Article getCurentArticle(List<Article> articles, String key) {
        int i;
        for (i=0; i < articles.size(); i++)
            if(articles.get(i).getArticleId()== new Integer(key)) break;                    ;
        return articles.get(i);

    }

где:
Article - класс, в котором у меня описан объект Статья,